# Cancel a string.replace

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string that is modified by several `string.replace('x','y')` and those replaces commands are activated by checkboxes, and I haven't been able so far to automatically reverse the process when one of the checkboxe is unchecked. The only solution I found would be to do a `string.replace('y','x')` when the checkboxe is unchecked...
Is there any other way that would be cleaner?

Comment: Just keep the original string separate from the transformation.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you asking? Just store the original string?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Let me make myself clearer, I have an original text (that I keep separated)and a set of rules to correct this text, the set of rules is  displayed via checkboxes, and I want that when a checkbox is unchecked  it cancel that particular rule in the corrected text... hope it's clearer.

Comment: Model your problem with objects or anything but not a string... You can always trivially get a string out of the object model if you need one.

Comment: My concern you already doing it in a correct way.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to my answer. I think it solves your problem.

Comment: @CaseyChu He's asking how to undo multiple replacements in a modular way. He may have several replacements applied at once, and he'll want to undo any of them as he pleases (using the checkboxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, doing string.replace('x','y') and then string.replace('y','x') to undo it would not work. Here's why:

starting string: "zxyxz"
string.replace('x','y') gives you "zyyyz"
string.replace('y','x') would then give you "zxxxz", which is clearly not what you started with.

Here's a fiddle with what you want I think:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/XZE9v/1/

It will re-apply the rules every time a checkbox is clicked / unclicked.

In case you can't see it here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="originalText" />
    <br/>
    a|x<input type="checkbox" data-find="a" data-replace="x" onclick="updateRegex()" />
    <br/>
    b|y<input type="checkbox" data-find="b" data-replace="y" onclick="updateRegex()" />
    <br/>
    c|z<input type="checkbox" data-find="c" data-replace="z" onclick="updateRegex()" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="display"></div>
```

JS:

```
function updateRegex() {
    var original = document.getElementById("originalText").value;

    var newString = original;

    var elems = document.getElementById("myForm").childNodes;

    for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
    {
        if ( "checkbox" == elems[i].type && elems[i].checked)
        {
            var regexp = new RegExp(elems[i].getAttribute("data-find"), 'g');
            newString = newString.replace(regexp, elems[i].getAttribute("data-replace"));
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = newString;
}
```

Comment: Woops, posted the wrong fiddle; I edited and put the correct one.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I did, I just run the original through the rules every time a checkbox is checked and unchecked.... thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that holds the values of the initial string. Perform all checkbox operations on the array. Get the final output string using this array.

```
var array = ['Moe','Chuck','Larry']
function findItem(val){
 var index = array.indexOf(val);
if(index != -1){
 array[index] = val;
}
}
 function onSubmit(){
 return array.toString();
}
```